# How to change y axis range to percent (%) from number in barplot with R (sjp.frq)

Tags: r, plot, frequency, percentage

everybody!

Does anyone know how to change y axis range to percent (%) from number in barplot using the package SjPlot? I want to set the range to percent from 0 - 100.

Here is the code that I used

```
sjp.frq(CAAPORA$Q2, type = c("bar"), sort.frq = c("desc"), geom.colors = "grey", show.na = TRUE, axis.labels = c( "Infantil", "Fund (Inicial)", "Fund (Final)"))
```

The y axis is in number (as you can see in the image)

[image: Graph 1]

Comment: Please show example code + data for producing this plot

Comment: What part of "+data" are you having difficulty with? (And the package name is "sjPlot".)

Comment: I am trying to change y axis range to percent (%). I already tried the package 'scales' and it did not work.